# Save/load the location(x,y,z) of selected vertices

Tags: python, blender

In blender, I have multiple objects. With one object (lets called it `Obj1`), which is the object I am editing, it does not allow me to add/delete vertices, faces, or edges (requiring the vertex's ordinal number of the object to be unchanged). All other transformations (`rotate`, `scale`, and `move`) are fine, but we can freely do anything with other objects.

I want to save the location (`x`,`y`,`z`) of selected vertices of `Obj1` into a file so I can restore the location of the saved when I need (all other vertices are not affected). The ordinal number of vertices of `Obj1` will never change during my edit, so I think I should be able to save the location of the vertex with its ordinal number like this

[vertex ordinal number]-[x]-[y]-[z]

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! While this question is programming related, you would probably find more help in the Blender Stack Exchange site (http://blender.stackexchange.com/), which is designed for Blender-specific questions.

Comment: I see ,Thank you very much :)